# Bilirubin metabolism pathway in non-human primates (NHP)?

Tags: metabolism

In human UGT1A1 seems to be the only relevant enzyme to glucuronidate unconjugated bilirubin into excreted forms. Is the pathway the same for e.g. the Cynomolgus monkey (Macaca fascicularis) in vivo? In case UGT1A1 is potently inhibited are there any other potential enzyme to glucuronidate/metabolise unconjugated bilirubin in NHP? Any reference would be highly appreciated.